# If Statements Outside of Functions in Controllers?

Tags: angularjs

In retrospect it seems obvious since a controller is a function, but I didn't realize you could do this:

```
  if(true){
    $scope.testValue = 'If statement changed my life forever'; 
  }
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/sILfsBwh1hfs9kZQUFW1?p=preview

Is this an accepted practice? Is there anything wrong with it? It seems to be roughly equivalent to using an IIFE inside a controller.

Comment: What's the point of that? it is in no way the same thing as an IIFE, it doesn't create it's own scope. the if conditional mightaswell just be removed. http://plnkr.co/edit/8gpNTPLrRoiGEclABBe1?p=preview

Comment: I don't really know - I found it in the code written by my (now fired) co-workers that love doing random $%#@, like making async .ForEach loops in C# with the sole purpose of looking clever and causing multi-threading errors. Anyway, off the bitter tangent - it just seems like a way of avoiding writing an init function to call a function which would include the if statements. So you could 1. $scope.foo = function(){//if statement} and then $scope.foo(); or put foo in an init function, or make foo an IIFE. Those are the alternatives I know.

Comment: @KevinB: Oh, saw your plnkr - the condition comes from a resolve from the parent controller (and this directive is used in various parent controllers). The "if(true)" part was just for sake of example.

Comment: Generally, `if (true) {...}` is the result of soft deleting a conditional that you needed before, but don't need anymore. It can typically be removed completely.

Comment: Ah, gotcha, so just a bad example. What is the "practice" you are asking about then, if `true` would be replaced, with, say, `someparam.length`

Comment: Just using the if statement outside of a function (though I suppose a controller is technically a function).I am asking if there is any downside as compared to the three+ other ways of doing it that I mentioned in the earlier comment.

Comment: No, none that i'm aware of. Like you said, it's just a function.

Comment: I think I got it. You can definitely do that but it is better to wrap all your controller initialization logic in an "activate" function. check out my plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/MtSHWy40rnRYirrbrbOE?p=preview . Also take a look into the angular-styleguide, you can find more tricks like this one https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide

Comment: Thanks Cesar - read the style guide ages ago, when I was newer to angular, most things didn't stick. Should revisit.